# GetDlgItem, works in one class and not in another

Tags: windows, mfc

I am trying to use the function GetDlgItem(int id) and not the GetDlgItem(HWND par, int id). In other parts my code I use GetDlgItem as such

```
CWnd * pWnd;
pWnd = GetDlgItem(IDC_UPPER_BTN);
```

And it works fine. But in another class I am trying to do the exact same thing and it keeps demanding a HWND.

When I search GetDlgItem I see there is a MFC and a windows version. How can I specify which one I want to use?

Comment: Hello! There is no need to put solved in the title as the "check" system already does the job! For more information see http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/172501/community-edit-request-solved-fixed-answered

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can specify the member function explicitly using:

```
this->GetDlgItem(...);
```

You can specify the global function explicitly using:

```
::GetDlgItem(...);
```